# SQL - How can I count days by comparing current row to the 1st row?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I have a table as below in the database, how can I write a SQL to show the expected result?

- first_date: the first order_date on the table ORDER BY order_date ASC
- days_to_date: (order_date - first_date) in number of days

My table:

```
id | order_date | order_ref
---+------------------------
 1 | 2015-03-01 | BC101
 2 | 2015-03-01 | BC102
 3 | 2015-03-02 | BC103
 4 | 2015-03-03 | BC104
```

Expected result:

```
id | order_date | first_date | days_to_date
---+------------+------------+-------------
 1 | 2015-03-01 | 2015-03-01 | 0
 2 | 2015-03-01 | 2015-03-01 | 0
 3 | 2015-03-02 | 2015-03-01 | 1
 4 | 2015-03-03 | 2015-03-01 | 2
```

Other notes:

- I'm using HSQLDB 2.0.0, but prefer solving the problem of getting the first_date displayed on every row in general cases if that's possible

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is inefficient. A better solution would be to calculate it when you INSERT and store it in a separate column, assuming that the first date never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select id, order_date, 
      (select min(order_date) from your_table) as first_date,
      datediff('day', (select min(order_date) from your_table), order_date) as days_to_date
from your_table
order by order_date
```

Comment: Brilliant! select min(order_date) solves the problem :D

Comment: See, for performance wise, it is better to get the min(order_date) in one variable, then use this variable in the select statement.

Comment: @OSAMAORABI: How do you know that? If the optimizer works good, doing it in one query is probably faster.